# Aws Event Bridge Notifications for the Different Environments

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, notifications, aws-event-bridge, amazon-ivs

I am Using the Aws IVS for live streaming . when the stream ends I need to get the notification. I have configured the Event Bridge with source as IVS and destination as DEV, QA and PROD endpoints. when the streams ends I am getting the notification in all the endpoints.

But my requirement is, if streaming starts from the dev, only dev endpoint should receive the stream end notification. if streaming starts from qa, only qa endpoint should receive the stream end notification. how to achieve this ? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and we end up creating and event-bridge for production, one for develop and another for staging.
Depending of the environment the producers sends to one event-bridge or another, same with the consumers.
the price remains the same